# Reading bitset<0> from istream always a failure?

Tags: c++, iostream

I was recently working with `std::bitset<0>` and noticed something interesting with [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_ltltgtgt2):

The "specification" states that:

> If no characters are extracted, is.setstate(ios_base::failbit) is called.

Does this still apply when "all possible N characters" (with N == 0) have been read? If so, does this imply that trying to read from an `istream` into a `bitset<0>` must always set `failbit`?

The following unit test exhibits no consistent behavior across the compilers I had at hand:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(io0) {
    try {
        std::stringstream ss{"1"};
        ss.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);
        std::bitset<0> b;
        ss >> b;
        BOOST_TEST(false);
    } catch(...) {
        BOOST_TEST(true);
    }
}
```

MSVC 2019 sets the failbit, whilst GCC 7.3.0 does not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [specification](http://eel.is/c++draft/bitset.operators#6) (no scare quotes) said the same thing (*when this question was asked*), so yes.  (Of course, skipping whitespace first may provoke some other kind of failure instead.)  I thought this a clear error in the standard, so I [filed an issue](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3199) which has since been resolved for C++20.

Comment: My only observation from reading through the linked draft is that a similar case (`std::array<T, 0>`) is explicitly mentioned in the standard, whilst `bitset<0>` is not mentioned whatsoever...

Comment: @MFH: So it sounds like 0 is valid (`array` has to mention it because of its otherwise-invalid exposition-only array member).